# Как сохранить значение диалогового окна при повороте экрана?

Tags: android

В активности создается диалоговое окно через класс `Dialog`, назначаю заранее подготовленный макет и кнопки. Какие действия мне нужно предпринимать для сохранения содержимого диалога и отображения при повороте?

Comment: `пользователей?` А оскорблять то зачем? :)

Comment: извиняюсь, если задел чьи-либо чувства, хотя, оскорбительного подтекста  не вижу

Comment: @cosmic_M, попробуйте через DialogFragment сделать. Там есть как и у обычного фрагмента методы для сохранения и восстановления состояния. У обычного диалога их нет

Comment: Вам необходимо чётко сформулировать вопрос, а точней ответить, есть ли у вас возможность использовать DialogFragment вместо Dialog.

Comment: Сегодня переделаю под  DialogFragment и протестирую... Я так понимаю, что в MyDialog (дочернем классе DialogFragment) нужно  указать в onCreate(){... setRetainInstance(true);}. Вот только мне не ясно: мой диалог будет автоматически присоединятся к хосту и отображаться при повороте экрана, или нужно будет через метод show() с тагами его отображать принудительно?